# How can I access my Activity's instance variables from within an AlertDialog's onClickListener?

Tags: java, android, scope, instances

Here's a very simplified version of my `Activity`:

```
public class Search extends Activity {

    //I need to access this.
    public SearchResultsAdapter objAdapter;

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem itmMenuitem) {


      if (itmMenuitem.getItemId() == R.id.group) {

          final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder.setTitle(itmMenuitem.getTitle());

          builder.setSingleChoiceItems(lstChoices),
              0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                  //I need to access it from here.
                }

              });

          AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
          alert.show();

          return true;

        } 

    }

}
```

When the menu button is pressed, my applications pops up an `AlertDialog`. When creating the `AlertDialog` and in-line `onClickListener` is attached to the each of the items in the dialog. I need to access the `objAdapater` variable that is defined in my `Search` activity. I don't have access to the search instance within my `onClickListener` so I can't access it. I have a little bit of a soup in my code with the passing of the `Activity` instance everywhere. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

How would I get access to the `Activity` (`Search` instance) from within my `onClickListener` so I can access it's methods and variables.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Search.this.objAdapter` to access `objAdapter` from the listener should work.

`Search.this` refers to the current instance of `Search` and allow you to access its fields and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Make your activity implement OnClickListener:

```
public class Search  extends Activity implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener { ...
```

Add the onclick method to your activity:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
     //I need to access it from here.
}
```

Then pass your activity as the listener:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(itmMenuitem.getTitle());

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(lstChoices),0, this);
```