# How can I call an activity within the same activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity that creates a list based on a list of series values returned by an http request. If the list includes a list of places, I call the next activity and pass some values through intents. However, if the response does not include a list of places, I need to repopulate my activity with a new list of series values, but I'm not sure how to call the same activity within the activity I'm already in. My attempt is below.

EDIT: the goal of refreshing the activity is to make an https request with new parameters in the url. I tried just recalling the http request earlier, but had no luck

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
        ArrayList<String> modelNames = new ArrayList<>();

        Log.d("JSON RESPONSE", result.toString());

        final ArrayList<JSONObject> modelsObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject info = result.getJSONObject("info");
            JSONArray models = info.getJSONArray("models");

            for(int i = 0; i < models.length(); i++){
                modelsObjectList.add(models.getJSONObject(i));
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < modelsObjectList.size(); i++){
                modelNames.add(modelsObjectList.get(i).getString("name"));
            }

        } catch(JSONException e ){
            Log.d("JSONEXCEPTION", e.getMessage().toString());
        }

        //TODO found problem, model names for whatever reason is passing in the names from previous activity
        Log.d("MODEL NAMES", modelNames.toString());
        Toast.makeText(AfterDestinationActivity.this, modelNames.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        CustomMainAdapter mainAdapter = new CustomMainAdapter(AfterDestinationActivity.this, modelNames);
        mList.setAdapter(mainAdapter);


        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            String name;
            Long id;
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                JSONObject passingObject = modelsObjectList.get(position);
                ArrayList<String> nextPlacesList = new ArrayList<>();
                Log.d("AD OBJECT PRESSED ON", passingObject.toString());

                //TODO found issues with debugging
                try {

                    JSONArray places;
                    JSONArray series = passingObject.getJSONArray("series");

                    name = passingObject.getString("name");
                    id = passingObject.getLong("id");
                    Log.d("NEXT ACTIVITY NAME", name);
                    System.out.println("NEXT ACTIVITY ID " + id);
                    Log.d("NEXT SERIES LIST", nextPlacesList.toString());

                    //if there are no places, launch http request again for series
                    if(passingObject.optJSONArray("places") == null){
                        ArrayList<String> sameSeries = new ArrayList();
                        System.out.println("WENT INTO FOR LOOP");
                        for(int i = 0; i < series.length(); i++){
                            sameSeries.add(series.getString(i));
                            Log.d("AD FOR LOOP SERIES", series.getString(i));
                        }
                        Intent refreshActivity = new Intent(AfterDestinationActivity.this, AfterDestinationActivity.class);
                        refreshActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        refreshActivity.putExtra("id", id);
                        refreshActivity.putExtra("name", name);
                        refreshActivity.putExtra("placesList", nextPlacesList);
                        Log.v("RESTARTING ACTIVIY", "activity restating");
                        startActivity(refreshActivity);

                    }

                } catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.d("JSONEXCEPTION", "IN THERE " + e.getMessage());
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(AfterDestinationActivity.this, PlacesListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("placesList", nextPlacesList);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I wound't do it like that. You are doing too much work on onPostExecute which I assume it located inside the activity. Try to put it in separate modules. E.g you download the data, you parse(in the background thread not UI thread).  After it is parsed you return the result to the activity, like I described below. Next you decide where to put ur data, either in your main activity or start a new activity. This, what you are doing here is just not good. Your code has some flaws that can lead to some nasty bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this,
add this in your manifest,

```
<activity android:name=".StartActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
</activity>
```

From JAVA code use this,

```
 Intent refreshActivity = new Intent(AfterDestinationActivity.this, AfterDestinationActivity.class);
                        refreshActivity.putExtra("id", id);
                        refreshActivity.putExtra("name", name);
                        refreshActivity.putExtra("placesList", nextPlacesList);
                        Log.v("RESTARTING ACTIVIY", "activity restarting");
                        startActivity(refreshActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the same activity. Just update the corresponding views with the new values in your activity.

Comment: The new views depend on an http call that I'm making within the same activity. So my first attempt was at just recalling the http request, but I had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would access it via the "this pointer" or an interface: 

**EDIT**

```
MyActivity extends Activity implements IUpdateListener
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle onSaveInstanceState)
    {
      //code
    }

    @Override
    void onUpdate(Result result)
    {
       //update data or do other stuff - like start another activity or populate urs.
    }
 }
```

Next The AsynTask:

```
    MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Result>
   {

       private IUpdateListener listener;
       public MyAsyncTask(IUpdateListener listener)
       {
          this.listener = listener;
       }

       Result doInBackground(Void.. voids)
      {
          //http request and parse - an object Result
         return result data;
      }
      void onPostExecute(Result result)
      {
         if(result!=null) - or other operation u want
         {
            listener.OnUpdate(result) - or other stuff you want.
         }
      }
```

Next the interface:

```
interface IOnUpdateListener
{
   onUpdate(Result result);
}
```

"this pointer":
[How can I access my Activity's instance variables from within an AlertDialog's onClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157561/how-can-i-access-my-activitys-instance-variables-from-within-an-alertdialogs-o) 

I hope I was clear enough.